# Mailkit: Recieved MimeMessage contains wrong embedded Images

Tags: c#, pop3, mailkit, mimekit

We use Mailkit in a ServerApp which queries (Pop3) periodically mails from our Exchange Server and
Store them in a Database.
This ServerApp runs in a Docker-Linux Container.

With another App we display the mails HTML-Body.
Thats works very well. All embedded images are correct.

But in one special case (specific customer),
we only see the standard web image when a linked image was not found.
(This little image which show a file with small red cross).
At first i thougt that these images are linked images which are not availabe.
The HTML-Code offers that these images were embedded.
But when we recieve this Mail with Outlook, which queries mails from our Exchange Server, too,
we see the embedded screenshots from the Customer.

After some research and debugging i noticed that the MimeMessage contains these "file not found" images instead of the customers screenhots, after the call from **Pop3Client.GetMessageAsync()**.

Actually i have no Idea why this happens.

Any suggestions? ^^

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.